# How to build a cross-platform mobile application using common C++ Business Logic and Data Access Layers

Tags: c++, iphone, android-ndk, windows-phone, cross-platform

We are trying to create an Application for all mobile platforms (Android, iPhone, Windows phone). We will build the User Interface using the native development languanges for each platform (Java, Objective C, C#). For the intermediate layers (DataAccess Layer and Business Logic Layer) we plan to use C++ for all platforms.
 We are going to use libraries like Curl, sqlite3, libzib. So I think a good solution would be to create two seperate C++ projects (DataAccess and Business Logic) and make references to those libraries we need. First we are going to start with Android, so I will include those two projects as prebuilt static libraries using Android NDK and in the jni folder I will add some methods that they will communicate between UI and Business Logic. Later we will do the same for the other two platforms. Since I am very new to C++ I would like to make the following questions:

1. Do you think that this theoretically will work?
2. What problems are we going to face (e.g debugging, using Curl in different operating systems)?
3. Are there any open source mobile projects using the same approach?

Comment: As far I know [Qt Mobile Edition](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-for-Mobile-Development/Qt-Mobile-Edition/) offers a pretty good cross mobile app platform. In general your question if off topic for SO (see my close vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think that this theoretically will work?

Yes, I've written and app for Android and iOS that uses a data access layer written in C++ on both platforms. I wrote the Android edition and a colleague wrote the iOS edition. It is not open source, so I can't show you the code.

> What problems are we going to face (e.g debugging, using Curl in different operating systems)?

Debugging the shared C++ code can be a pain in the ass on Android. I've never gotten the debugger for work on Windows. I normally resort to careful reading of my code and printing messages to LogCat if it is not something I can reproduce and debug on iOS. Normally this only affects the JNI layer that links the C++ business logic and the native UI code.

You'll probably have to build 3rd party libraries separately for platform. Curl has instructions for building it for each platform so that shouldn't be much trouble.

Apart from learning JNI, the biggest problem I had was that the app had to look the same (or very similar) on each platform. I'd recommend looking into [Qt Mobile Edition](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-for-Mobile-Development/Qt-Mobile-Edition/) as 
πάντα ῥεῖ suggested, however it doesn't currently support Windows phone. Still, you would be able to write one UI for two of your three platforms at least - and your shared business code would still be reusable. We are in the process of starting a second app and Qt is definitely looking like the best option for us. I don't think we'd want to repeat the experience of trying to provide the same functionality on two platforms using very different APIs.

> Are there any open source mobile projects using the same approach?

I'm not aware of any off-hand, but I'm sure you can Google it.

Comment: So speaking for Android what strategy do you think is better?       1. include the curl, libzip, etc. libraries inside the jni as seperate static libraries 2.  include them as references to the business logic c++ project and then include this as prebuilt static library to the android.mk

Comment: I can't say which is "better" because I don't know. Having just double checked, we are actually doing a bit of both in our first app but that only has two dependencies. For the next app we are planning on just building a set of prebuilts and including them in the static library, but then we have a bunch more dependencies and it seems easier to manage this way. Building each for the different platforms is managed by separate build scripts which make use of the standalone toolchain.